# StackReader for iPad

Tags: app, ipad

### Screenshot

[image: Stack Reader for iPad icon]
[image: StackReader - list of questions]
[image: StackReader - sample question]
[image: StackReader - select your stack view]

### About

StackReader is the Stack Exchange Network on your iPad.

Feature highlights:

- access to all Stack Exchange Network sites (including most popular
  ones: Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User) on your iPad,
- follow your favorite tags, people or questions matching any search queries,
- browse questions grouped in several categories,
- built-in browser to access all functionality not yet provided by Stack Exchange Inc. (like asking questions, answering, voting, commenting),
- offline access to questions and answers,
- native iOS app, with its look & feel, sorting, searching, and sharing the most interesting questions by e-mail,
- Retina display ready

#### License

StackReader 2 is in the works, it will be separate, paid app.

#### Download

App Store: TBA.

#### Platform

All Apple retina iPads (iOS 7.1 or above).

### Contact

Piotr Byzia

http://stackreaderapp.com/

Please report any bugs here: https://stackreader.tenderapp.com/discussions/stack-reader

Twitter: [@StackReader](http://twitter.com/#!/stackreader)

Comment: Absolutely awesome icon :)

Comment: Nice icon :) Would love to see an iPhone version near future. Is that possible?

Comment: @kolor Everything is possible ;) Stay tuned (e.g. by subscribing to our newsletter at http://stackreaderapp.com or Twitter: http://twitter.com/#!/stackreader)